# Backbone Routing with Static HTML files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

I'm working on a website where we are using 3rd Party web services to return dynamic content and using javascript to parse and display that data from to the page. We are already using backbone in a couple places on the site to post data to web services so I had the thought of trying to use Backbone's router to run specific functions based on the page url and grabbing the query because we are hashing the queries to the url of the page.

For example: global-site-search.html#query

This is the router code I have to this point:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        '' : 'indexRoute',
        'global-site-search.html(:query)' : 'getSearchResults'
    },

    indexRoute: function(query) {
        console.log("indexRoute");
    },

    getSearchResults: function(query) {
        console.log("getSearchResults with query", query);
    }
});

var WaRouter = new Router();

Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: '/'
});
```

But when I hit the page with a url like global-site-search.html#query the query value returns null. Has anyone tried this before or am I trying to extend Backbone's router to far in handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `global-site-search.html` from your server?, if yes then the config for router should be

```
':query' : 'getSearchResults'
```

If no, then you can't do that, because `Backbone.Router` uses the `hash` part of the current page URL to track pages. And since `global-site-search.html` is not containing any backbone code, it can't do anything. It is possible only if you somehow can inject your router code into `global-site-search.html` which is illegal in this case

Updated: this should allow you to search with this route `':query' : 'getSearchResults'`

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: window.location.pathname
});
```

When using router, you need to set the correct root, so using `window.location.pathname` is the easiest way to do that. Also, according to Backbone documentation

> and if a hash URL is visited by a pushState-capable browser, it will be transparently upgraded to the true URL. Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100`

Since you are not having any real back-end to handle pushState, I suggest that you turn it off

Comment: global-site-search.html is from the server. I set the router up that way because there is going to be another page location-lookup.html that does the same thing just with location look up. So my plan was to set that up as a route as that would fire the function that gets the data for the location look up and why I set the root to '/'.

Comment: That works, but it fires that route on any hashed url which is causing problems on other pages. Think I'm going to have to write a more custom router that will only fire on the specific pages.